# Transitioning from the old PayPal button to the PayPal Javascript SDK button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-buttons

I have used the plain paypal button like this with no problems:

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.net">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Website Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Donation via PayPal"  ><br></form>
```

and moved to this style to get Venmo and Credit card options:

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=secret&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"Site Donation","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":1.99}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            
            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

I have a IPN page to receive the order information from the original button and it checks the item_name and item_number field from that.

My questions is, will the description (Website Donation) from the createOrder section translate to those same fields or will the description be a new field (what is it called)?

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"Site Donation","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":1.99}}]
          });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of your [sandbox Business accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts), set a sandbox [IPN listener URL](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify).

Create a [REST app](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications%2F) for that particular sandbox business account, and copy its client ID. Use that client ID to create a sandbox test payment, using a sandbox Personal account to approve the payment.

Log the data from the sandbox IPN you receive. It will have the available fields for that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could have tested it, but anyhow.  I created a 1.99 butt and had someone use it.  The "description" used in the new button came through with the field name of &transaction_subject=Site Donation&.